# подскажите почему этот код грузит страницу

Tags: javascript

```
for (i=0;i<10;i++) {
    if (getDigitsSum(getDigits(i)) == 13 ) {
        document.write(i + ' ');
    }
}

function getDigitsSum(arr) {
    var sum = 0;
    for(i=0;i < arr.length;i++) {
        sum = sum + Number(arr[i]);
    }
    return sum;
}    

function getDigits(num) {
    var str = String(num);
    return str.split('');
}
```

Comment: Какого результата вы хотите добиться этим кодом? Он ведь никогда ничего не выведет...

Comment: обратите внимание на область видимости переменной i

Comment: @СергейМаяк Ну область видимости - глобальный) Потому что она нигде не объявлена через let... вот функция, вызванная внутри цикла - сама тоже запускает цикл и кажется в процессе меняет i так, что внешний цикл становится бесконечным)

Comment: Спасибо за четкий ответ

Comment: это ещё хорошо что обе i недалеко друг от друга, так глобальная переменная может выдать  глюк находясь в вообще в другом конце скрипта если функция вызывается ещё где то

Answer (score 0):

Если вдруг вам нужен более рабочий вариант то можно сделать вот так

```js
for (i=0;i<500;i++) {
    if (getDigitsSum(getDigits(i)) == 13 ) {
        document.write(i + ' ');
    }
}

function getDigitsSum(arr) {
    return arr.reduce( (s,v)=>parseInt(s)+parseInt(v) );
}    

function getDigits(num) {
    var str = String(num);
    return str.split('');
}
```

или ещё короче

```js
for (i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
  if (String(i).split('').reduce((s, v) => parseInt(s) + parseInt(v)) == 13) document.write(i + ' ');
}
```

Comment: >_< и еще объявлять переменную в цикле... `for( let i = 0...` P.s. кстати, я и сам не  могу понять причину ошибки) Понятно, что цикл бесконечный, но не понятно почему выводит всегда 2 ) У автора, `getDigits(i)` - вот там, даже в первом вызове, i передается как 2...

Comment: getDigitsSum завершается с i=1 (длина массива) а затем i инкрементируется в основном цикле for (i=0;i<500;i++) { до двойки и так по кругу всегда двойка